# PHP: Can I print a current time in this format? (00:00:00:)

Tags: php, datetime

Can I print a current time in this format? (00:00:00:)

```
echo date("H:i:s","00:00:00");
```

**output: 01:00:00**

I want output: 00:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can with `strtotime()`:

```
echo date("H:i:s",strtotime("00:00:00"));
```